# Login Panel/Form no more displaying after securing the connection to the GWT application using SSL

Tags: java, ssl, gwt, ssl-certificate, tomcat8

I have a GWT module/application deployed in Appache Tomcat and I have secured the connection to the application using SSL (so that one connects to it via https:// instead of http://  as it has been the case so far).So  I created CSR (Certificate Signing Request), gave it to the IT guys of my Company who signed it using the company's Root Certifcate and issued me a Certificate chain which I imported to Tomcat keystore. Everything works fine with firefox and Chrome (The connection is secured). But I have a problem with IE11. Although the connection is also secured in IE11, there is a Login Panel/Form on the first page which is not displayed. Before we decided to secure the connection to the application, the login form was there and everything was working fine.

When I go to Developer Tools -> DOM Explorer of IE, I see that there is indeed a login form (username/password field and submit button) as you can see on the picture below :

[image]

I am just wondering was is the problem hier and I would appreciate any help  because i am stuck.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Does the IE11 console show any warnings or errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After an investigatation , I found out that the problem with the login form not displaying in IE had to do  with the settings for compatibility mode for Internet Explorer in the Development Tools. So I changed the Document Mode from 7(Standard) to 11 as follows :

```
    -> Press F12
    -> From the Document Mode List Box ,select 11
       Note : 7(standard) was selected instead as default.
    -> Refresh the browser and problem Solved.
```

[image]